# Image inside a GridControl -Devexpress

Tags: wpf, devexpress

I have a grid control in which the first column and cell shows a trash icon. But the trash icon should be visible only when its row is selected.

I have a style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageStatusStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.IsFocused,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>                
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and a data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TrashIconCellTemplate" >
    <Button Height="15" Width="15"  Command="{Binding ElementName=GroupCodeListView,Path=DataContext.MarkRowForDeletionCommand}">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="../Resources/crane.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageStatusStyle}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
</DataTemplate>
```

A grid control:

```
<dxg:GridControl ItemsSource="{Binding GroupCodes, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 SelectedItems="{Binding                    
                 SelectedGroupCodes,Mode=TwoWay}"
                 SelectionMode="Row"
                 x:Name="Grid"
                 ClipboardCopyMode="ExcludeHeader" 
                 Margin="0,0,0,0"
                 Height="360"
                 MinWidth="400"
                 CustomRowFilter="FilterDeleted">
```

and the grid cell column referencing the above:

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="IconUnbound"
                UnboundType="Object"
                CellTemplate="{StaticResource TrashIconCellTemplate}"
                CellStyle="{StaticResource GroupCodeColorStyle}" />
```

The trash image in the first cell should appear when the row is selected only.

The image remains in the default state of hidden. The data trigger is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check whether the row is selected then you need to use [`RowData.IsSelected`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridRowData_IsSelectedtopic) property. Also, you must set the `Visibility` in your `Style` section, not in the `Image` itself.

Here is example:

**0. Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="ImageStatusStyle">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RowData.IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**1. Image:**

```
<Image Source="../Resources/crane.png" Style="{StaticResource ImageStatusStyle}" />
```